# Сохранение сессии php

Tags: php, сессия

подскажите пожалуйста как можно в сессию сохранить два значения, а то получается test2 перезаписывает test

```
session_start();
if($_POST['test']) { 
    $_SESSION[${$_POST['test']}] = $_POST['test'];
}
if($_POST['test2']) { 
    $_SESSION[${$_POST['test2']}] = $_POST['test2'];
}
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
        <input value="1" style="display:none" name="test"> 
        <button type="submit">test</button> 
</form>
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
        <input value="2" style="display:none" name="test2"> 
        <button type="submit">test2</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: А зачем вы используете значение в качестве ключа?

Comment: В качестве примера записал)

Comment: Ну так не используйте значение в качестве ключа, а сделайте два нормальных строковых ключа (например `"test"` и `"test2"`) и никто никого перезаписывать не будет

Comment: `${$_POST['test2']}` - что это? Откуда? "Доктор, когда я делаю так, мне больно! А вы не делайте так!". Зачем писать какую-то сложносочиненную конструкцию, чтобы обратиться к элементу массива? Для ПОСТа же вы такую не пишете почему-то? А здесь в чем смысл?

Comment: эх, старый добрый $$, я уже почти забыл его))

Answer (score 0):

```php
// это только пример, для использования в продакшне нуждается в доработке
session_start();

function setSessionByKey(string $key): void
{
    if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}

setSessionByKey('test');
setSessionByKey('test2');
```

Comment: Во-первых, вряд ли нужна специальная функция для добавления в сессию из массива POST. Во-вторых, если уж функция написана, то её название никак не отражает суть - от функции setSessionByKey() любой программист будет ждать просто добавление переменной в сессию, и про пост даже не подумает. В-третьих, функция молча ничего не сделает, если в массиве пост нет переданного элемента. Такое неявное поведение приведет к проблемам с отладкой

Comment: ОК, с моей стороны нужно пояснение, зачем в принципе эта функция была написана. Только за тем, чтобы не дублировать одинаковый код. И да, согласен со всеми перечисленными замечаниями. Однако я не ставил цель написать идеальную функцию, которая тут же полетит в рабочий репозиторий, я лишь хотел предоставить автору рабочий пример для его кейса. Поэтому, да, извиняюсь, что не написал пояснения.